# Ctime, mktime in C

Tags: c, time.h

I can't have the `time_in` printed out right, can you please show where my code went wrong? Thank you and hope you have a great day!

> **Input:** `55 17:30 11-06-2023 07:15 15-07-2023`, the first number is the price for renting a bike (not very neccessary), and numbers after that are the rent time and the return time in the form: HH:MM DD-MM-YY, print out the rent time and the return time in the form `long int` using `mktime` and in the standard form (e.g `Sat Jul 15 07:15:01 2023` )  using `ctime`

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int price;
    scanf("%d", &price);

    struct tm input_time;
    struct tm output_time;
    time_t time_in, time_out;

    scanf("%d:%d %d-%d-%d", &input_time.tm_hour, &input_time.tm_min, &input_time.tm_mday, &input_time.tm_mon, &input_time.tm_year);
    scanf("%d:%d %d-%d-%d", &output_time.tm_hour, &output_time.tm_min, &output_time.tm_mday, &output_time.tm_mon, &output_time.tm_year);

    input_time.tm_mon -= 1;
    output_time.tm_mon -= 1;
    input_time.tm_year -= 1900;
    output_time.tm_year -= 1900;

// printing out every component to check if i failed to input them
    printf("%d\n", price);
    printf("%ld:", input_time.tm_hour );
    printf("%ld ", input_time.tm_min );
    printf("%ld-", input_time.tm_mday );
    printf("%ld-", input_time.tm_mon );
    printf("%ld\n", input_time.tm_year );

    printf("%ld:", output_time.tm_hour );
    printf("%ld ", output_time.tm_min );
    printf("%ld-", output_time.tm_mday );
    printf("%ld-", output_time.tm_mon );
    printf("%ld\n", output_time.tm_year );
    
//using mktime
    time_in = mktime(&input_time);
    time_out = mktime(&output_time);

// print out the time in seconds form
    printf("%ld\n", time_in);
    printf("%ld\n", time_out);

// print out the time in the 'Sat Jul 15 07:15:01 2023' form
    printf(ctime(&time_in));
    printf(ctime(&time_out));
    
}
```

> Here're my output, i got the return time printed right, but the rent time is all messed up, i keeps changing everytime i run the code

1st run:

```
550000        
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123 
1592440040    
1689380101    
Thu Jun 18 07:27:20 2020
Sat Jul 15 07:15:01 2023
```

2nd run:

```
550000        
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123 
-2085243656    
1689380101    
Mon Jan 09 19:07:20 2040
Sat Jul 15 07:15:01 2023
```

Comment: `%ld` is the wrong format type.

Comment: Unlike normal functions, an `int` argument for a variadic function like `printf()` which is expecting a `long` argument will not be automatically promoted to `long`.

Comment: What C compiler and operating system are you using? I'm asking because I remember some universities forcing their students to work with ancient Borland compilers on (emulated) MS-DOS machines.

Comment: `printf("%ld:", input_time.tm_hour );` ==> `printf("%d:", input_time.tm_hour );`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
struct tm input_time;
struct tm output_time;
```

These are on the stack. So, they are *uninitialized*. The parts of the structs that you don't *explicitly* set can have random values.

This is because they take on *whatever* values just "happen" to be there from earlier parts of the execution of the program.

This is UB (undefined behavior).

To fix this, initialize all elements to zero:

```
struct tm input_time = { 0 };
struct tm output_time = { 0 };
```

Note that although you *did* check *some* values, some *others* (e.g. `tm_isdst`, `tm_sec`, etc.) were *not* initialized. These values are filled in by (e.g. `localtime`) but `mktime` [is finicky and] needs some more of them.

Also, some `printf` used `%ld` instead of `%d`.

---

On *my* system, the UB always produced consistent results. That's the nature of UB. It can work, work intermittantly, be incorrect, segfault.

So, to simulate the random behavior, I refactored the code to use `rand` to pre-seed the structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int opt_z;

void
timeget(struct tm *tm)
{

    unsigned char *bp = (unsigned char *) tm;
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(struct tm);  ++idx) {
        // simulate properly initialized values
        if (opt_z)
            bp[idx] = 0;

        // simulate uninitialized value (i.e. random values)
        else
            bp[idx] = rand();
    }

    scanf("%d:%d %d-%d-%d",
        &tm->tm_hour, &tm->tm_min, &tm->tm_mday, &tm->tm_mon, &tm->tm_year);

    tm->tm_mon -= 1;
    tm->tm_year -= 1900;
}

void
timeout(const struct tm *tm)
{

    printf("%d:", tm->tm_hour);
    printf("%d ", tm->tm_min);
    printf("%d-", tm->tm_mday);
    printf("%d-", tm->tm_mon);
    printf("%d\n", tm->tm_year);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int price;

    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    srand(ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec);

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'z':
            opt_z = ! opt_z;
            break;
        }
    }

    scanf("%d", &price);

// NOTE/BUG: these are uninitialized
    struct tm input_time;
    struct tm output_time;

    time_t time_in, time_out;

    if (opt_z)
        printf("structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)\n");
    else
        printf("structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)\n");

    timeget(&input_time);
    timeget(&output_time);

    // printing out every component to check if i failed to input them
    printf("%d\n", price);
    timeout(&input_time);
    timeout(&output_time);

    //using mktime
    time_in = mktime(&input_time);
    time_out = mktime(&output_time);

    // print out the time in seconds form
    printf("%ld\n", time_in);
    printf("%ld\n", time_out);

    // print out the time in the 'Sat Jul 15 07:15:01 2023' form
    printf(ctime(&time_in));
    printf(ctime(&time_out));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the input that I used to test:

```
55 17:30 11-06-2023 07:15 15-07-2023
```

---

Here is the "bad" output for 5 runs:

```
structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1566767832
3210324873
Sun Aug 25 17:17:12 2019
Thu Sep 24 08:54:33 2071

structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
887606802
3740157022
Mon Feb 16 00:26:42 1998
Thu Jul  8 16:30:22 2088

structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
394103670
-316448899
Mon Jun 28 05:14:30 1982
Tue Dec 22 04:31:41 1959

structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
192016368
127026679
Sun Feb  1 04:52:48 1976
Thu Jan 10 01:11:19 1974

structs will be seeded with random values (uninitialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1519761782
3264962288
Tue Feb 27 15:03:02 2018
Sat Jun 17 17:58:08 2073
```

---

Running the program with `-z` a few times:

```
structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1686522600
1689423300
Sun Jun 11 18:30:00 2023
Sat Jul 15 08:15:00 2023

structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1686522600
1689423300
Sun Jun 11 18:30:00 2023
Sat Jul 15 08:15:00 2023

structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1686522600
1689423300
Sun Jun 11 18:30:00 2023
Sat Jul 15 08:15:00 2023

structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1686522600
1689423300
Sun Jun 11 18:30:00 2023
Sat Jul 15 08:15:00 2023

structs will be seeded with zeroes (initialized)
55
17:30 11-5-123
7:15 15-6-123
1686522600
1689423300
Sun Jun 11 18:30:00 2023
Sat Jul 15 08:15:00 2023
```